# Entity Framework AddOrUpdate implementation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create a extension method similar to [AddOrUdpate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx).

The usage should be like this:

```
var student = context.Students.GetOrCreate(
    s => s.Name, 
    new Student() { Name = "SomeName" })
```

If there is any user with that name it should return it, otherwise it should create the new user.

This is what I have:

```
public static TEntity GetOrCreate<TEntity>(
    this IDbSet<TEntity> set,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> identifierExpression,
    TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    var func = identifierExpression.Compile();
    var id = func.Invoke(entity);
    var persistedEntity = set.FirstOrDefault(e => func.Invoke(e) == id);

    if (persistedEntity != null)
    {
        return persistedEntity;
    }

    return set.Add(entity);
}
```

But I can't call `invoke` using LINQ to Entities.
How should I use the `identifierExpresion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it to create a new expression that you can pass into FirstOrDefault and let the EF provider handle converting the expression to SQL.  The new expression will test equality with the id you retrieved from the compiled and invoked expression.  Something like this:

```
var equalityExpr = Expression.Equal(identifierExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(id));
var findMatchExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equalityExpr, identifierExpression.Parameters);
var persistedEntity = set.FirstOrDefault(findMatchExpr);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something like that, but didn't realized that first parameter for the equals method should be the body of the identifier expression

Comment: lol, I made the exact same mistake and was getting an exception there - my unedited post said "something like this but it doesn't work"